# get and post table type using pqxx

Tags: c#, c++, sql, stored-procedures, libpqxx

Good day, friends. I'm using `pqxx` and I have some questions.

**1. I have two tables:** 
`table1 (table1_id integer) and table2 (table1_id integer, another_id integer)` with relation one-to-many.
How I can easy get information in view like: table1_id, vector another_ids?
Now I use serializtion in script (string concat into "%d %d %d...") and deserialization in my c++ code.
Also I need insert value into table1. And how I can do this in one transaction?

**2. I call stored procedure like**

```
    t.exec("SELECT * FROM my_proc(some_argument)");
```

May be exists any way to do this like in c#?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So, may be it can help someone.

**In first case** I find and use two ways:
1. Group concat in sql function and deserialization in c++. It fast if table2 has only table1_id and another integer.
2. I call two function: get_table1() and get_table2() with order by table1_id. And then with two pointers I create array of table1:

```
std::vector<Table1> table1Array;
auto ap = wrk.prepared(GetTable1FuncName).exec();
auto aps = wrk.prepared(GetTable2FuncName).exec();
auto pos = aps.begin();
for (auto row = ap.begin(); row != ap.end(); ++row) {
    std::vector<Table2> table2Array;
    while (pos != aps.end()
           && row["table1_id"].as(int()) == pos["table1_id"].as(int())) {
        table2Array.push_back(Table2(pos["first_id"].as(int()), 
                                     pos["second_string"].as(std::string())));
        ++pos;
    }

    Table1 tb1(row["table1_id"].as(int()), row["column2"].as(int()),
               row["column3"].as(int()), row["column4"].as(int()),
               table2Array);

    table1Array.push_back(tb1);
}
```

May be it is not pretty, but it's working.
Insert into database I write for one element. Firstly insert into Table1, and after several lines into Table2. After call `pqxx::work.commit()`.

**In second case** Not, doesn't exists. Also remember, function always return 1 line! Be careful!